# Search in multiple tables by eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables: `posts` and `pages`. Based on the keyword, I want to search different columns of the two tables for the occurrence of keyword. The two tables do not have related content.

I have written two queries one for each table. Following are the queries:

```
$result1 = Post::where('title_en', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->or_where('title_np', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->order_by('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);

$result2 = Page::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->or_where('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->order_by('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
```

The above queries return two different `Laravel\Paginator` object. But I want a single `Laravel\Paginator` object so that a single pagination is displayed on the page which works for both the queries or on a single query which achieves the functionality of both the above queries. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: SQL UNION is the best way for this, IMO. But you may have to go with raw queries for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are unrelated tables, you need to do some trickery that's simply too complex for Eloquent to handle, you need to do something similar to the following to join the two queries together, and still be able to do your limit / ordering on the combined queries:

```
$results = DB::query('SELECT id, title FROM ( 
SELECT id, title FROM `post` where `title_np` LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%" OR `title_en` LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title FROM `page` where `title` LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%" OR `content` LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"
) temp_table
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 0, 10
')
```

NB the above is untested, purely an example of the approach you'll need to take, not sure this will actually work.

Comment: the raw query using union works, but apparently `paginate()` doesn't work on raw queries. Is there any way to make raw queries work with paginate?

Comment: Though that might be the case, looks like you may have to do this manually, i.e., set the `limit` and `skip` yourself in the query.

Comment: I guess I have no other way than to manually set the `limit` and `skip` by myself in the query. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Edited the answer just in case someone else comes along to see this

Comment: You can always wrap the result of your query in a collection and use paginate method of collection

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered ages ago but If someone ends up here like me, I had a very similar issue, and here is how I did it using the eloquent way :

```
$users = User::where('active', 1)
         ->where(function ($subQuery) use ($searchKeyword) {
    
             $subQuery->where('pseudo', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%")
             ->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%")
             ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%")
             ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%");
       })
         ->whereHas('addressPrincipal')
         ->select(array_merge(['id', 'pseudo', DB::raw("CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name) as name")],
                [DB::raw('"user" as source')]));
    
$usersAll = Subsidiary::where('active', 1)
         ->where(function ($subQuery) use ($searchKeyword) {
    
             $subQuery->where('slug', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%")
              ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%")
              ->orWhere('email_principal', 'LIKE', "%$searchKeyword%");
         })
         ->unionAll($users)
         ->select(array_merge(['id', 'slug as pseduo', 'name'],
               [DB::raw('"subsidiary" as source')]))
         ->paginate(10);
```

You must have noticed that I have used array_merge in the select statement, I have done this as I needed to know from which table respective records were getting fetched.