# Join two completely different tables in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to join two different tables, say, '*questions*' and '*case_study_posts*'. These table don't have a common key to fetch record.
I would like to show both question posts and case study posts in a page.
How do i do that?
Currently i'm fetching these two tables individually and sort accordingly, then merge these two collections and again sorting.
Now , i'm thinking to simplify these logic in to 'fetch both table at once and do the sorting'
here's what i used in the 1st scenario

```
$questions = resolve('question')->getListingByFollowers($followings_id,$sort,$per_page,true);
$CaseStudyPosts = resolve('case-study')->getListingByFollowers($followings_id,$sort,$per_page,true);
```

This is the case study repository which have the function *getListingByFollowers()*

```
public function getListingByFollowers($id,$sort = null,$per_page = 10, $paginate = false){
        $listing = $this->caseStudyPost
        ->with(['user.votes','votes'])
        ->where('is_active','Y')
        ->whereIn('user_id',$id);

        if(\Auth::user()->role->role_code == config('constants.ROLES.USER.STUDENT')) {
            $listing->whereIn('category_id', config('constants.STUDENT_VIEW_CATEGORIES'));
        }   else {
            $listing->whereNotIn('category_id', config('constants.STUDENT_ADD_CATEGORIES'));
        }
        if($sort == null || $sort == 'newest'){
            $listing->orderBy('created_at','desc');
        }elseif($sort == 'votes'){
            $listing->orderBy('created_at');
        }
        if($paginate){
            return $listing->paginate($per_page);
        }
        return $listing->get();
    }
```

*getListingByFollowers()* in the question repository has almost same structure like this

Comment: as per my understanding, you can use laravel relationships between tables.

Comment: Like how? any links to refer will be helpful

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080964/search-in-multiple-tables-by-eloquent-query