# Search by joining two tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, search

I am searching the jobs with `title` successfully from the `jobs_table`. It has `id, title, city_id, created_at`. I have another table naming `cities` having `id, name`. I just want to add both the tables and search by `name` of the city also.

Job Model query:

```
public static function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm)
{
   return $query->where('job_title', 'like', '%' .$searchTerm. '%');
}
```

Controller Query :

```
public function indexsearch(Request $request) 
{
  $searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');
  $posts = Job::search($searchTerm)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('job_status', '0')->paginate(10);
  return view('front.pages.job.jobresult', compact('posts', 'searchTerm'))->with(['title'=>'Result']);
}
```

Blade Query :

```
<form action="{{ route('job.jobresult') }}" method="GET" id="search-form_3" class="mb-4">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="search_3" name="searchTerm" placeholder="Search for Jobs..." value="{{ isset($searchTerm) ? $searchTerm : '' }}">
      <input type="submit" class="submit_3" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Till now everything is fine with single table search, Now I just want to join both tables and then search by `name` of the city also.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Job Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Job extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'job_title','city_id'
        ];
    
    
        public static function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm)
        {
            return $query->where('job_title', 'like', '%' .$searchTerm. '%');
        }
    }
```

City Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cities';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

I have tried :

```
return $query->where('cities.city', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->join('cities', 'jobs.city', '=', 'cities.id');
```

its working but how can I add another fields in it.

Comment: have you attempted to do this yet?

Comment: not much, I have tried but not get any eaxact solution

Comment: Also, its working fine when searching from one table

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far

Comment: Leave it, it was not helpful. Can you please suggest how can I achieve the required output. By this way, How can I do that

Comment: I guess this question is repeated, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080964/search-in-multiple-tables-by-eloquent-query

Comment: It is different, I think you have not read the question properly dude,

Comment: @BhaweshBhakar Can you show us your models?  This seems easily solved with a one to many relationship.

Comment: @Daedalus I have added above my Job and City models,

Comment: Check my above added query, I have tried something like that

Answer (score 0):

As per your most recent edit, assuming that `city_id` is the name of the column on your jobs table(and not `city` as shown in the very last line of your question), the following should do what you want:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_title','city_id'
    ];
    
    
    public static function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm, $cityName)
    {
        return $query->where('job_title', 'like', '%' .$searchTerm. '%')
            ->join('cities', 'jobs.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
            ->where('cities.name', 'like', '%' . $cityName . '%');
    }
}
```

There's not much to really explain; just add additional parameters to the scope as you need them.

You've already found the join syntax, so the remaining answer of how to add additional data is to add a where clause to the query builder instance with the joined table's name with an extra parameter supplied to the static function.

It's use is as simple as you'd imagine:

```php
// assuming $cityName is defined...

$posts = Job::search($searchTerm, $cityName)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('job_status', '0')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Tested in Laravel 5.7, 7, and 8.